# Does setting project.build.sourceDirectory work in maven properties?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a project using a non-standard, maven directory structure.

Does setting project.build.sourceDirectory work in maven properties using maven 3.6.0 and maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0 ?

I tried using:

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/my_source_dir<project.build.sourceDirectory>
</properties>
```

But this didn't work. The compileSourceRoots defaults to My_project_path\src\main\java

Placing the sourceDirectory in the  section does work.

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/my_source_dir<sourceDirectory> 
...
```

Is this a bug or is project.build.sourceDirectory unsupported ?

Comment: Think about moving to the standard layout. It will make your life easier.

Comment: It's not my choice at the moment.. How to move to "moving to the standard layout" was not question.

Comment: First as @JFMeier mentioned: Using standard layout helps a lot and should be first choice. Whoever made choice should reconsider this strongly. If you decide for a tool you should follow it's intentions (convention over configuration). Furthermore why using a property ? Which can never work cause the properties are evaluated later.

Comment: I suppose you can solve it using build-helper-maven-plugin
"add-source" goal give possibility to add sources from other folders during build phase

Comment: @ khmarbaise, I known that maven 'likes' to use the enforced structure, the transition will be gradual to get there.  Philosophically, maven team support any way to override the build structure, but hey do. I have used it before and it has worked in the past.  It just doesn't work now. I was wondering why. I bet other are as well. Using a property vs build sections allows others, not familiar with maven, to ease supporting the multi-pom build after i"m gone.

Comment: @ khmarbaise,  Properties are evaluated early on and placed in the environment. In the case of maven-compiler-plugin, the source path is recalled via project.getCompileSourceRoots() from class org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject . Looking at the code, it appears setting in properties is no longer supported, but is may be referenced. In MavenProject.java a comment says: " There is still the issue of having to run the lifecycle in order to find all the compile source roots and resource
 * directories but I hope to take care of this during the Maven 4.0 release (jvz)."

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO.

Setting project.build.sourceDirectory in the properties section is not supported in maven 3.x. The project.build.sourceDirectory property may be referenced as a read only property. Source directory(ies) must be set in the  section using  tag.

An alternative is noted by Gmugra, use the build-helper-maven-plugin via the  tag during the generate-sources phase. See: https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html